# Cover letter v/s statement of research interests

Tags: application-cover-letter

I saw a postdoctoral position advertisement in engineering field, which has asked applicants to submit a ***cover letter***  and a ***statement of research interest***. If these two are not explicitly asked, then I usually prepare single document mostly containing my research interest along with a CV.

I would like to know what should be the content of the two different documents, means what should go where?

Thanks

Comment: For me, the cover letter is about _who you are_ (and why do you fit to the position). The research statement is _what you want to do_ (and have done before).

Answer (score 1):

Statement of research interest seems to deal specifically with you potential future research. Though, you can obviously base your future project describing your proved past record. The cover letter seems to be a general info, something that you are XYZ  who completer PhD in ABC university, has the following background and you are interested in this position. In the cover letter I would briefly mention your research interests and refer for more details to the  statement of research interest.

I think that there is nothing special about this two-letters format, but it is just some bureaucratic requirement of the university.  May be worth asking them  how long should be research statement - because you can potentially write one page or 15 pages like a full grant.

Comment: one page of statement of research